# Is there Excel Power Query formula to do "exist" or something similar?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I want to code the solution to get the result below in Excel Power Query Editor .

I have :

[image]

If between Jan,Feb,March for each code there is "Y" exist then Y Else N
--So even if one Month we have Y then I want to see Y if for all of available month there is N then N

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

- Group by `Code`
- Test each subGroup to see if there is a "Y" in any of the rows:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Code", type text}, {"Date", type text}, {"Y/N", type text}}),
   
 #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Code"}, {
        {"YN", each if List.MatchesAny(Table.Column(_,"Y/N"), each _ = "Y")
                    then "Y" else "N"}
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

***shorter code and case insensitive matching***

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Code", type text}, {"Date", type text}, {"Y/N", type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"Code"}, {
        {"YN", each if List.MatchesAny(_[#"Y/N"], each _ = "Y" or _ = "y")
                    then "Y" else "N"}
        })
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

[image]

***Note** Recall that PQ is case sensitive, so you may need to check for both `Y` and `y` if that might be an issue.*

Answer (score 0):

Since there are only two options, you can do Group By and use Max as the aggregate since `Y` is alphabetically after `N`.

[image: Group By GUI]

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WqlDSUfJy9AOSkUqxOhC+m6sTkPSD830dg+DylWjylXB5CL8K2bxYAA==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Code = _t, Date = _t, #"Y/N" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Code", type text}, {"Date", type text}, {"Y/N", type text}}),
    #"Lowercased Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Y/N", Text.Lower, type text}}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Lowercased Text", {"Code"}, {{"Y/N", each List.Max([#"Y/N"]), type nullable text}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

The extra step here is to first put everything in lowercase for consistency (and since that's you specified the output).